# Is it possible to remove opportunity and account from salesforce1 navigation menu?

Tags: salesforce1-app

I need to remove opportunity and account fields on salesforce1 navigation menu. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean you want to hide Opportunities and Accounts tabs from the menu for a particular user profile? Why don't you edit that profile and select 'Tab Hidden' in Standard Tab Settings? Alternatively, you could update permission sets -> object settings -> tab settings to hide tabs. Or, did you mean not to give read/write permissions to the two objects at all? If yes, change the permission in the respective profiles and/or permission sets.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to do it according to the profile level. But I need to do affect only for the salesforce1 navigation menu. Not for the desktop UI. Is it possible to do using salesforce configurations?

Answer (score 1):

> Anything represented by a tab in Salesforce—such as standard and
>   custom objects, Visualforce pages, the Chatter feed, People, or
>   Groups—is visible for a user in the Salesforce1 menu, based on the
>   user’s profile settings. For example, if a user is assigned to a
>   profile that has the Groups tab set to Tab Hidden, the user won’t see
>   the Groups menu item in Salesforce1, even though an administrator has
>   included it in the menu.  Objects that aren’t available in
>   Salesforce1, including any objects that don’t have a tab in the full
>   Salesforce site